# eclipse-plugin how to open standard View like InternalWebBrowser with Java

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In Eclipse plugin development **How to open standard View like InternalWebBrowser** or bring up/activate Console View (all those standard things)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open the `Internal Browser` you need this code:

```
int style = IWorkbenchBrowserSupport.AS_EDITOR | IWorkbenchBrowserSupport.LOCATION_BAR | IWorkbenchBrowserSupport.STATUS;
IWebBrowser browser = WorkbenchBrowserSupport.getInstance().createBrowser(style, "MyBrowserID", "MyBrowserName", "MyBrowser Tooltip");
browser.openURL(new URL("http://www.google.de"));
```

Alternative:

```
final IWebBrowser browser = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getBrowserSupport().createBrowser("abc");
browser.openURL(new URL("http://www.google.de"));
```

To open a `view` use this:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView(arg0);
```

Comment: @Paul Verest did that help you?

Comment: The first option worked fine. However in IDE there is warning : "Discouraged access: The method getInstance() from the type WorkbenchBrowserSupport is not accessible due to restriction on required library D:\Progs\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.105.0.v20130529-1406.jar    
"